# Could not receive Push notification with demo GCM source of google

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm using demo code of google about GCM. Here's [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)

I run code on 2 devices Docomo(4.0.3) and Sony(5.0).
But only Sony was received the push notification.

On Docomo devices, I used to uninstall and reinstall Google Play Services. Before I reinstall Google Play Services on this devices, I received push well. So I don't know that effect to push notification

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/id84k0h5u5rzvn3/GCM_Log?dl=0) log which I got when run demo code of Google on Docomo devices

If you have any idea to resolve this issue, please share for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you uninstalled Google Play services completely or just uninstalled updates?

Comment: I uninstallled Google play services completely

Comment: Ohh and how you reinstalled it back? Using play store or manually pushing apk?

Comment: After uninstall, I run gcm demo code of google. At main Activity, apps will check Google play services, and I downloaded from play store

Comment: You weren't able to receive notifications when Google Play Services is installed and only able to receive notifications when Google Play Services is uninstalled on the said device? Is that right? How many times have you tried this and is the behavior consistent?